# Getting blocks of zeros after flashing SD card with dd

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, dd

I've got a problem with writing an SD card with an image. What I want to do is to create an image of an SD card from files present on my hard drive.

**My plan is to:**

1. Create a loop device and connect it with `sd_card.img` filled with zeroes.
2. Use `fdisk` to create 4 partitions right where I want them to be (I store some raw data between the partitions).
3. Create the file system on each partitions with `mkfs.msdos LOOP_DEVICEpX`, where `X` is number of the partition.
4. Mount each of the partitions to `partX` folder on my hard drive, copy some files to them and unmount the partitions.
5. Create an image of the loop device using `dd`.

**Main problem:** When I try to write an SD card with the created image everything goes smooth but I get some blocks of zeros in my files. Eg. I open some .wav file and it contains its header, some data and then at 0x00001200 begins some blocks of zero data that is not in the original file. It ends at 0x00004000, so it has 0x2E00 which is to equal (23 * 512). I checked the image I write an SD card with and it doesn't contain the zero blocks that are present inside my file on the SD card.

**Main question:**
Why does `dd` put some zero blocks of data on the SD card during write when they're not in the input image file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried with a different SD card?

Comment: some things to check: block sizes the same, dd's "conv" option, are the zero's part of the filesize of the file or just the default you filled the image with.